# Terminal's "Use custom default terminal size" property does not work

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to make custom property for terminal size. My changes has no effect and Terminal still starts in full screen mode.

Comment: The problem is with all apps as I've noticed !

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal starts in fullscreen mode because you set a size bigger than your current display.

Remember that the size here is not given in pixels but in characters.

The default size is 80x24, so if you tried to set up a 1920x1200 terminal this way you'll always get a fullscreen terminal window.

I'd suggest lower values to solve your problem, try first with 80x48 and slowly increase to see what fits your needs.

Comment: I have tried to change the size. It has no effect !

Comment: Repost of a comment by promet heus: If I put in 20x20 the terminal (Ubuntu 14.10) should create a small square window, if I'm understanding this correctly. It actually creates a window that is, roughly, three times higher than it is wide. The horizontal does adhere to the 20 character designation. It seems like the vertical though is, seemingly, a lot more than twenty characters. "Low-balling" the vertical axis value gets me a lot closer to what I'm trying to get, visually at least.